Fixing badly formatted floats with numpy
I am reading a text file only containing floating point numbers using numpy.loadtxt. However, some of the data is corrupted and reads something like X.XXXXXXX+YYY instead of X.XXXXXXXE+YY (Missing E char). I'd like to interpret them as the intended floating point number (or NaN if impossible) and wondered if there was any easy way to do this upon reading the file instead of manually correcting each entries in the file since it contains hundreds of thousands of lines of data.
MWE:
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("path/to/datafile")

Example of error raised:
ValueError: could not convert string '0.710084093014+195' to float64 at row 862190, column 6

You could use the python RE module (and a regex with a negative lookbehind) to go through the file, and find and replace any +'s that appear without a preceding E.

Put that into a function and use the converters argument.

A MWE needs to include example input data and desired output. For reference see [mre]

@Ben That wouldn't work if any floats are formatted like +0.0, though that seems unlikely.

@wjandrea You could use a positive lookbehind to require a number before +, so it won't match a number with a sign at the beginning. The same approach will be needed if the file can contain negative numbers and negative exponents.

r"(?<=\d)(?<!E)[\+\-]" should work

@BenGrossmann your re idea worked. If you create an answer I'll mark it as solution

The following works:
import numpy as np
import re 

def converter(txt):
    txt = re.sub(r"(?<=\d)(?<!E)[\+\-]", lambda x: 'E'+x[0], txt.decode())
    return float(txt)

np.loadtxt("path/to/datafile", converters = converter)


I think you can read the file and replace
# Open and read text file
with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # Read line
    for line in file:
        # Trim string
        line = line.strip()

        # Replace + without e before to e+
        processed_line = re.sub(r'(?<!e)\+', 'e+', line)

